# What is the true filename on my server?

Tags: ftp, content-encoding

I have created a pdf under the name `André.pdf` on my server. However, I am not sure if this is the actual filename.

I first assumed `André.pdf` is the actual filename because I can access it through

`www.mydomain.net/Andrè.pdf`

However, when I connect with Filezilla to my server I see the following filename depending on the charset options:

- `AndrÃƒÂ©.pdf` (Detect charset automaticly)
- `AndrÃ©.pdf` (Force
  UTF-8)
- `AndrÃÂ©.pdf` (Using charset iso8859-1)

If I use the terminal to access the folder via ssh I see `André.pdf`.

What is the actual filename on my server and how can I find it out? Is it *Andrè.pdf* because I can access it with`www.mydomain.net/Andrè.pdf`? If this is the case, what do I need to change in FileZilla to display the file correctly?

Comment: FYI: Urls/filenames should be lowercase, no weird characters (like é) and no spaces. Filenames should not me charset sensitive.

Comment: Not true Martijin, linux doesn't use Charset, browsers and other applications do. Linux files can be named any BYTE other than `NUL`, `/`, `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real filename would be exactly the same filename you originally named it. Your only limitation is that set out by the operating system and the filesystem.

> OK, so looking at [Comparison of file
>   systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) if
>   you only care about the main players file systems:
>
> - Windowz (FAT32, NTFS): Any Unicode except `NUL` and `/`
> - Mac(HFS, HFS+): Any valid Unicode except `:`
> - Linux(ext[2-4]): Any byte except `NUL`
>
> so any byte except `NUL`, `/`, `:` and you can't have files/folders
>   call `.` or `..`

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352640/1892635))

Applications may use CHARSETS but this isn't renaming the file locally, its simply translating the file, the original file renames unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[FileZilla has a Wiki page about this issue with character sets](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Encoding)

To paraphrase, it says that:

- FTP originally allowed only ASCII characters
- Some servers and clients violated the spec and implemented international characters with a locally chosen character set
- The FTP protocol was changed to allow UTF-8 instead of just ASCII
- FileZilla uses the UTF-8 character set and *only* UTF-8 despite that some servers may (incorrectly) use something else

You need to change your FTP server or reconfigure it to use the UTF-8 character set in order to be compatible with FileZilla.